# Why are UTF-8 encoded values (in language.properties) misinterpreted in Liferay 6.2?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, liferay, properties-file, liferay-6.2

In Liferay Portal 6.2 i have created a portlet that has `language.properties` file.
The `portlet.xml` like this :

```
<resource-bundle>com.test.portlet.featuretest.content.Language</resource-bundle>
```

The `language.properties` reads:

```
no-customer-were-found=no customer
first-name=FIRST NAME
last-name=\u0646\u0627\u0645 \u062E\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0627\u062F\u06AF\u06CC
```

In the `view.jsp` there is somthing like this :

[image: view.jsp]

why utf characters not loaded.  (??? ????????)  but in the liferay 6.0.6 everything is true.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was Liferay 6.1 where the default encoding for localization property files changed from the Java standard to UTF-8 - in other words your language files should just contain the unescaped UTF-8 encoded characters rather than the hard-to-read version that you're posting above.

Just convert them to the correct encoding, convince your IDE that it's fine to have UTF-8 encoded property files and you're set.